# Elasticsearch: Ordering of Highlighted results does not work

Tags: elasticsearch, highlight, elasticsearch-5

I am trying to order the highlighted results returned by Elasticsearch. As per the documentation, here is how I do so:

enter code here res=es.search(

```
        index="my-index",
        size=30,
        body=
        {

        "query":
             {
                 "multi_match":
                  {
                      "fields":["chapter_name","chapter_id","subchapter_name","subchapter_id","range_name","range_id","item_name","item_id"],
                       "query": "diamond core bit adapters" ,
                       "type":"best_fields",
                        "fuzziness": "1",
                      "tie_breaker": 0.3
                   }
        },

        "highlight" :
        {

        "type":"unified",
        "order": "score",
        "fields" :
            {
            "chapter_name" : {},
             "chapter_id" : {},
            "subchapter_name":{},
            "subchapter_id":{},
            "range_name":{},
            "range_id":{},
            "item_name":{},
            "item_id":{}

            }

        },

        })
```

However, as part of my results I get something like this:

```
{u'item_name': [u'<em>Core</em> <em>bit</em> <em>adapter</em> DDBU 1 14 UNC'], u'subchapter_name': [u'<em>Diamond</em> Drilling Accessories'], u'chapter_name': [u'<em>Diamond</em> <em>Coring</em>  Sawing'], u'range_name': [u'<em>Diamond</em> <em>core</em> <em>bit</em> <em>adapters</em>']}
```

Clearly, the field 'range_name' has higher number of fragments highlighted, but it appears lower down the order.

Can anyone help me out with this?